# Proving the bijection of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am having some trouble understanding why the function $f : R \rightarrow R $ defined by $f(x) =2x$ would be bijective. This is because I cannot understand how can the function be surjective? Wouldn't  the function only give us even numbers as outputs? So if odd numbers like $5,7$ are part of the codomain but not of the range then how is the function surjective? Thank you for your help

Comment: What is $R{}{}$?

Comment: It's the set of real numbers

Comment: So is there a real number $x$ such that $2x=3?$

Comment: @saulspatz oh sorry! I only thought about it in terms of integers

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you ! I understood it now

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Comment: This is a good time to give the reminder that to adequately describe a function you must include in its definition both the domain and the codomain.  The function $f~:~\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=2x$ is a different function than $g~:~\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ given by $g(x)=2x$.  Just simply saying "The function $h$ given by $h(x)=2x$" is ambiguous.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Exactly! I probably didn't think about it that earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both your domain and codomain are the real numbers. So for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, ask yourself for what $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it is the case, that $f(x) = y$.
That is $2x=y$ or $x=\frac{y}{2}$

Comment: Oh yes ! If we think about it that way then all of the real numbers would be a part of the range . Thank you for your help !

Comment: Exactly! You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If the function is mapped from R to R, then for any real X (integer or otherwise), $f^{-1}(x/2)=x$. However, if we map from Z to Z, then you’re right; for odd x, the value x/2 would not be in our domain, so our function could not be surjective.

Comment: Yes i get it now ! Earlier I was only thinking about it in terms of integers.  Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

If $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ is prescribed by $n\mapsto2n$ where $\mathbb Z$ stands for the set of integers then $f$ is not surjective since there is no integer that satisfies $2n=3$.

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto2x$ where $\mathbb R$ stands for the set of real numbers then $f$ is surjective, since $f(0.5x)=x$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for helping ! I understood it :)